# how to duplicatea char variable using a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, character

So I was wondering how to duplicate the letter c using a for loop. I have done this with the * sign, but can't seem to make it work with the letter c. I used the IBIO to get input. I need to know how to duplicate the c in the same way as the *. When I run the code, the c is only printed one time. Why is this? Please help me fix it.

```
 public class Methods
 {
     public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new Methods ();
    }


    public quadMethods ()
    {
        printNStars (5);
        printNChars (6, 'q');

    }


    public void printNStars (int n)
    { //prints 'n' stars on the screen in a row
    n = IBIO.inputInt ("Enter a number for 'n': ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
     System.out.print ("*");
    System.out.println ("");
    }


    public void printNChars (int n, char c)
    { //prints 'n' of character c on the screen in a row
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++);
    {
     System.out.print ("c");
    }
    System.out.println ("");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's caused by a rogue `;` after the `for` loop.

Comment: Change `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){`

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues. One is the number of iterations for both loops:

```
public void printNStars (int n)
{
    n = IBIO.inputInt ("Enter a number for 'n': ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        System.out.print ("*");
    System.out.println ("");
}
```

This will input a number and print `n+1` stars. You probably mean to do this:

```
public void printNStars (int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        System.out.print ("*");
    System.out.println ("");
}
```

Second problem is the semicolon in you other loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++);
```

This creates a loop that does nothing. Also the output statement outputs `c`s, not the passed in character!

Second function should probably be:

```
public void printNChars (int n, char c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.print (c);
    }
    System.out.println ("");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However I only get 6 c's printed when i run the program. Why is this?

Comment: Erhm... because you call it, asking for six: `printNChars (6, 'q');`...?

Comment: Then why don't I get 5 stars printed out ??

Comment: If you use my corrected version of `printNStars` and call it as `printNStars(5)` then you should get five stars

Comment: Never mind, thanks again